# Couldnt find error in the anagram program

Tags: c, anagram

I could not find what the error is in the following anagram program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int is_anagram(char* s1, char* s2){
        int i;
        char count[256] = {0};
        if(NULL == s1 || NULL == s2) return 0;
        for(i = 0; (s1[i] && s2[i]); i++){
                count[s1[i]]++;
                count[s2[i]]--;
        }
        if(s1[i] && s2[i]) return 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                if(count[i]) return 0;

        return 1;
}

int main(){
        int i;
        char* cases = malloc(10);
        char* str = malloc(500000);
        char* str1;
        char* str2;
        if(NULL == cases || NULL == str) return 0;
        fgets(cases,10,stdin);
        for(i = 0; i < atoi(cases); i++){
                fgets(str,500000,stdin);
                str1 = strtok(str," ");
                str2 = strtok(NULL," ");
                if(NULL == str1 || NULL == str2){
                 printf("\nNO");
                 return 0;
                }
                if(is_anagram(str1,str2)){
                        printf("\nYES");
                }
                else{
                        printf("\nNO");
                }
        }
        free(str);
        return 0;
}
```

I was trying to verify the number that is entered is an anagram or not.

I am inputing 3 strings to findour whether its anagram or not

i/p:
3
abc abc   - YES 
abc ba    - NO
a1b2c3 abc123 - YES

I couldn't get correct o/p for some of the i/p's like with the second string with lot of spaces.
How to optimise this further

Comment: why do you think its not efficient? Which specific code?

Comment: Why do you want to optimize incorrect code?

Comment: If it's not generating the correct result for some inputs, maybe you should run it under a debugger while it's processing one of the failing inputs.

Comment: 50000 - because 49999 isn't quite enough, and 50001 is just too many.

Comment: If inouted with lots of spaces between the two strings the program doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this line is useless (always false):

```
if(s1[i] && s2[i]) return 0;
```

What you probably meant was:

```
if(s1[i] || s2[i]) return 0;
```

Also, your code has the possibility of using negative indices into your `count` array since you are using signed characters as array indices.  On normal ASCII input, you are ok, though.